# If $y=\sin^2(a+\delta)$, then is there an expression for $\sin^2\delta$ in terms of $a$ and $y$?

Tags: trigonometry, transcendental-equations

Consider this equation:
$$y = \sin^2(a+\delta)$$

Can I get the expression of $\sin^2 \delta$ from this by any trigonometric manipulations? or is this a transcendental equation and can only be solved numerically?

Comment: Are you supposed to express $\sin^2\delta$ as a function of $y$ and $a$?

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales yes that's my aim.

Comment: It can be done. You will need a few identities such as $\sin^2\theta=\dfrac{1-\cos(2\theta)}{2}$ and $\cos(a-b)=\cos a\cos b+\sin a\sin b$ and possibly others.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the picture.

[image: Triangles]

$$
\begin{align}
|OA|&=1\\
|AB|&=\sin{(a+\delta)}\\
&=\sqrt{y}\\
|OB|&=\cos{(a+\delta)}\\
&=\sqrt{1-y}\\
\\
|AP|&=|AB|-|BP|\\
&=\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{1-y}\tan{(a)}\\
\\
|AQ|&=|AP|\sin{(90-a)}\\
&=\left(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{1-y}\tan{(a)}\right)\cdot \cos{(a)}
\end{align}
$$

Notice that $|AQ|=\sin{(\delta)}$. Try for different quadrants as well.

Comment: But then also the RHS contains term with delta(y term). That is again like a transcendental equation

Answer (score 0):

$$y = \sin^2(a+\delta)=\frac{1-\cos[2(a+\delta)]}2\implies \cos[2(a+\delta)]=1-2y$$ Using the inverse trigonomatric functions
$$\delta=-a\pm\frac{1}{2} \cos ^{-1}(1-2 y)$$
$$\sin^2(\delta)=\sin^2\left(a\pm\frac{1}{2} \cos ^{-1}(1-2 y) \right)$$